# Generating a deterministic int from another with no duplicates

Tags: go, random, random-seed

I'm looking to create a deterministic number generation function where the input number will always generate the same number, but no two numbers will end up generating the same result.

E.g.:

```
1 -> 3
2 -> 5
3 -> 4
4 -> 2
5 -> 1
```

However I need this to work for all numbers that can be represented by a specific datatype, e.g. an int64.

This feels like something that should either be really straightforward, or completely impossible. Is there some random number generation scheme that guarantees this sort of distribution without me having to create an array of all possible numbers, randomly sort, and then use the index (and making me run out of memory in the meantime)?

Many thanks
F

Comment: This is called a permutation and you'll find enough stuff online on how to generated a permutation, e.g. by slapping together a few cycles.

Comment: Technically speaking you didn't specify which properties of permutation do you require. These trivial ones `n -> n` or `n -> (n+1) mod 2^64` also satisfy your question :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transformation formula you need is:

```
f(P) = (mP + s) mod n

// n = range - so for uint64 2^64
// s < range i.e. < 2^64
// m = must be coprime with n
```

This is [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) as used in the [Affine cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher).

The `mod` ensures it is within desired range, `s` is a simple shift and `m` should be [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) with `n`.
Coprime simply means `n` and `m` should not share any common factors.
Since `n` is 2^64 its only factors are the number `2` - so `m` should basically not be even (i.e. not divisible by 2):

So for `uint64` range:

```
var (
    m = uint64(39293)    // some non-even number
    s = uint64(75321908) // some random number below 2^64
)

func transform(p uint64) uint64 {
    return p*m + s // implicitly mod'ed 2^64 by the type's size
}
```

This may appear magic, but you can convince yourself it works with `uint16`:

https://go.dev/play/p/EKB6SH3-SGu

(as `uint64` would take quite some resources to run :-)

---

***Update***:

For signed numbers (i.e. `int64`) the logic is no different. Since we know we have a unique one-to-one mapping with `uint64` one approach would simply be to convert inputs & outputs from `uint64` to `int64` and vice versa:

```
// original unsigned version
func transform(p uint64) uint64 {
    return m*p + s
}

func signedTransform(p int64) int64 {
    return int64(transform(uint64(p)))
}
```

again here's a `int16` example proving there's no collisions:

https://go.dev/play/p/Fkw5FLMK0Fu

Comment: Interesting. I need to spend a little bit of time convincing myself that this avoids duplicates and gives a uniform distribution... Is this transform called something? Can I read up about it somewhere?

Comment: update with math references & anecdotal test code

Comment: It is known also as Linear Congruential Generator, Hull–Dobell Theorem etc. Added as an answer below

Comment: "Since uint64 would take quite some resources to run". If you have access to exabyte storage, running it would be easy using jump-ahead method, cores are cheap.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I was referring to the Go playground which has an upper limit on execution runtime.

Comment: @colm.anseo I just thought for a test you need (before hitting initial seed and had to stop) a counter and 2^64 bits array - to set bits at the position where you generate value. Then you could check counter to be 2^64 and bit array for zeroes. 2^64 bits is 2^56 bytes - more than a petabyte, less than exabyte. Then with jump-ahead you could fill parts of the bit array at will, in parallel

Comment: @colm.anseo. Just one follow up as I’m struggling to figure it out. Is there a way of having this work for a signed integer data type, where the inputs will always be positive, but have all outputs be positive too? I’ve tried bitshifting the MaxInt64 I’m modding by to halve it, and then re-adding that to move it into the positive number space, but I must be doing something wrong as I’m always getting clashes. The only solution I have so far is recursively calling it if we get a negative number, which will work, but is horrible.

Comment: @FlamFace update answer with signed numbers example: the logic & one-to-one mapping guarantee remains the same.

Comment: Apologies, and thank you for being so comprehensive, I think I didn’t describe it well. This signed solution makes sense, but we get positive integers for a negative input, and vice versa. My goal, given that i know all inputs will be positive is to have all outputs be positive too. Basically, I want to mod with an int31 and shift by an int31 too, but I can’t seem to get that working…

Comment: If your type is `int32` you want to mod `2^31` so only positive numbers appear. A simple mask can perform this mod and will prevent the upper (negative) bit being set: `return (m*p + s) & (1<<31 - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

To add to [colm.anseo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218512/colm-anseo) answer, this kind of mapping is also known as [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

X<sub>n+1</sub> = (aX<sub>n</sub>+c) mod m

When c ≠ 0, correctly chosen parameters allow a period equal to m, for all seed values. This will occur if and only if:

- m and c are relatively prime,
- a-1 is divisible by all prime factors of m,
- a-1 is divisible by 4 if m is divisible by 4.

These three requirements are referred to as the Hull–Dobell Theorem.

For 64bit LCG a=6364136223846793005 and c=1442695040888963407 from Knuth looks good.

Note, that LCG mapping is 1-to-1, it maps whole [0...2<sup>64</sup>-1] region to itself. You could invert it if you want. And as RNG it has distinctive ability for jump-ahead.