# Fastest way to bring a range [from, to] of 64-bit integers into pseudo-random order, with same results across all platforms?

Tags: c++, optimization, cryptography, tbb, uniform-distribution

Given some interval [a, b] of indices (64-bit unsigned integers), I would like to quickly obtain an array that contains all of these indices ordered according to a uniformly distributed hash function, *appearing random* but actually being the same on every system, regardless of the used C++ implementation.

The goal is to find highly optimized such methods. You may use shared memory parallelism via Intel's [oneTBB](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/nested-index.html) to improve performance.

Something like

```
vector<uint64_t> distributeIndices(uint64_t from, uint64_t to) {
    unordered_set<uint64_t> uset;
    for (uint64_t i = from; i <= to; i++)
        uset.insert(i);
    return vector<uint64_t>(uset.begin(), uset.end());
}
```

would generate desired results if `unordered_set<uint64_t>` would always use the same and a pseudo-randomly distributed hash function on every implementation, both of which is not the case. It would also be an inefficient solution. TBB equivalent:

```
tbb::concurrent_vector<uint64_t> distributeIndices(uint64_t from, uint64_t to) {
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_set<uint64_t> uset;
    tbb::parallel_for(from, to + 1, [&uset](uint64_t i) {
        uset.insert(i);
    }); // NOTE: This is only to illustrate a parallel loop, sequential insertion is actually faster.
    return tbb::concurrent_vector<uint64_t>(uset.begin(), uset.end());
}
```

Note that `distributeIndices(from, to)` should return a random-looking permutation of {from, ..., to}.

- Merely providing some hash functions is insufficient, and none of the answers at "[Generating a deterministic int from another with no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72188054)" actually answered that question.
  Consider `transform` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72188615). Notably, a cyclic distribution is not a pseudo-random distribution:

  1. Sorting {from, ..., to} w.r.t. `(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) { return transform(a) < transform(b) }`

     - `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[0, ..., 999]` looks not random at all:
       [image: stackoverflow.com/a/72188615 sorted]
  2. Sorting {from, ..., to} w.r.t. `(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) { return transform(a) % n < transform(b) % n }`

     - `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[0, ..., 999]` looks not random at all:
       [image: stackoverflow.com/a/72188615 sorted modulo n]
  3. Assigning each `x` in {from, ..., to} to `transform(x - from) % n + from`

     - `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)` happens to be bijective (since `100000000` and `39293` are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers)), but `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[0, ..., 999]` looks not random at all:
       [image: stackoverflow.com/a/72188615 assigned modulo n]
     - `distributeIndices(42, 42+3929299)` is **not bijective**. It assigns only 100 different elements, cycling with a period of 100:
       [image: stackoverflow.com/a/72188615 assigned modulo n]
  4. Assigning each `x` in {from, ..., to} to `transform(x - from) + from`

     - `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)` is **not bijective**, e.g. it assigns `3929375282657 > 42+99999999`.
- In particular, a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is not in general a bijection. But if you can make it such for each interval [from, to], while also hiding its cyclic nature, *how*?

Consequently, an answer should provide a specific hash function (and why it is fast and uniformly distributed), **and** how to efficiently utilize it in order to compute `distributeIndices(from, to)`.

Again, it is crucial that `distributeIndices(from, to)` has the same result regardless of where it runs and what compiler it used, which must be guaranteed according to the C++ standard. But it is fine if for example `distributeIndices(0,2)` assigns a different index to `1` than `distributeIndices(0,3)` does.

Acceptable return types are [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [tbb::concurrent_vector](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/containers/concurrent_vector_cls.html), and [dynamic arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), consisting of elements of type `uint64_t`.
The function should perform well on ranges that include billions of indices.

[ In case you are curious on why this could be useful: Consider that there are different processes on different computing nodes, communicating via [Message Passing Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), and they should not send actual data (which is big), but only indices of data entries which they are processing. At the same time, the order to process data should be pseudo-randomized so that the progress speed is not "bouncing" much (which it does, when processing along the ordered indices). This is essential for reliable predictions of how long the overall computation will take. So every node must know which transformed index refers to which actual index, i.e. every node must compute the same result for `distributeIndices(from, to)`. ]

**The fastest correctly working solution wins the accepted answer.**

- No C/C++ code, no acceptable answer.
  (Except when it is a proof that the problem cannot be solved efficiently.)

I will test solutions with GCC 11.3 `-O3` on my old i7-3610QM laptop with 8 hardware threads on 100 million indices (i.e. `distributeIndices(c, c + 99999999)`), and may change accepted answers when future answers provide a better performing solution.

[Testing code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R8mI8DUDQbh08NU0) (run up to 10 times, pick fastest execution):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    uint64_t c = argc < 3 ? 42 : atoll(argv[1]);
    uint64_t s = argc < 3 ? 99999 : atoll(argv[2]); // 99999999 for performance testing
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> startTime = chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto indices = distributeIndices(c, c + s);
        chrono::microseconds dur = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
        cout << durationStringMs(dur) << endl;
        // [... some checks ...]
#if 0 // bijectivity check
        set<uint64_t> m = set<uint64_t>(indices.begin(), indices.end());
        cout << "min: " << *m.begin() << " , max: " << *prev(m.end()) << ", #elements: " << m.size() << endl;
#endif
        cout << "required average: " << round((2.0L * c + s) / 2, 2) << endl;
        long double avg = accumulate(indices.begin(), indices.end(), __uint128_t(0)) / static_cast<long double>(indices.size());
        string sa = round(avg, 2);
        cout << "actual average:   " << sa << endl;
        auto printTrendlineHelpers = [](uint64_t minX, string avgX, uint64_t maxX, uint64_t minY, string avgY, uint64_t maxY) {
            cout << "Trendline helpers:" << endl;
            cout << "[max] " << minX << " " << maxY << " " << avgX << " " << maxY << " " << maxX << " " << maxY << endl;
            cout << "[avg] " << minX << " " << avgY << " " << avgX << " " << avgY << " " << maxX << " " << avgY << endl;
            cout << "[min] " << minX << " " << minY << " " << avgX << " " << minY << " " << maxX << " " << minY << endl;
        };
        // Print some plottable data, for e.g. https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/scatter-plot.html
        unsigned plotAmount = 2000;
        auto printPlotData = [&](uint64_t start, uint64_t end) {
            long double rng = static_cast<long double>(end - start);
            long double avg = accumulate(indices.begin() + start, indices.begin() + end, __uint128_t(0)) / rng;
            cout << "\ndistributeIndices(" << c << ", " << c << "+" << s << ")[" << start << ", ..., " << end - 1 << "]: (average " << round(avg, 2) << ")" << endl;
            stringstream ss;
            for (unsigned i = start; i < end; i++)
                ss << i << " " << indices[i] << (i + 1 == end ? "" : " ");
            cout << ss.str() << endl;
            printTrendlineHelpers(start, round(start + rng / 2, 2), end - 1, c, sa, c + s);
        };
        printPlotData(0, plotAmount); // front
        printPlotData(indices.size() / 2 - plotAmount / 2, indices.size() / 2 + plotAmount / 2); // middle
        printPlotData(indices.size() - plotAmount, indices.size()); // back
#if 1 // Print average course
        if (s >= 1000000)
            plotAmount *= 10;
        stringstream ss;
        for (uint64_t start = 0; start < indices.size(); start += plotAmount) {
            uint64_t end = min(start + plotAmount, indices.size());
            uint64_t i = start + (end - start) / 2;
            long double avg = accumulate(indices.begin() + start, indices.begin() + end, __uint128_t(0)) / static_cast<long double>(end - start);
            ss << i << " " << round(avg, 2) << (end == indices.size() ? "" : " ");
        }
        cout << "\nAverage course of distributeIndices(" << c << ", " << c << "+" << s << ") with slices of size " << plotAmount << ":\n" << ss.str() << endl;
        printTrendlineHelpers(c, sa, c + s, c, sa, c + s);
        break;
#endif
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Storage of the result (e.g. via static variables) is obviously not allowed.
- `uint64_t from` and `uint64_t to` *cannot* be considered `constexpr`.

My two (unsuitable) examples would be `14482.83 ms (14 s 482.83 ms)` and `186812.68 ms (3 min 6 s 812.68 ms)`.
The second approach seems terribly slow, but upon closer inspection it is the only one that on my system actually distributes the values:

- `unordered_set<uint64_t>` variant:
  e.g. 100000041, 100000040, 100000039, 100000038, 100000037, ... // bad
- `tbb::concurrent_unordered_set<uint64_t>` variant:
  e.g. 67108864, 33554432, 16777216, 83886080, 50331648, ... // well-distributed, **but not looking random**

  - `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[0, ..., 999]` with polynomial trendline:
    [image: stackoverflow.com/q/76076957 example]
    The above distribution looks ordered, not random.

An exemplary distribution suggesting randomness can be obtained from [olegarch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76077930), as of Apr 30, 2023.

```
// LCG params from: https://nuclear.llnl.gov/CNP/rng/rngman/node4.html
std::vector<uint64_t> distributeIndices(uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi) {
    uint64_t size = hi - lo + 1;
    std::vector<uint64_t> vec(size);
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        vec[i] = i + lo;
    uint64_t rnd = size ^ 0xBabeCafeFeedDad;
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        rnd = rnd * 2862933555777941757ULL + 3037000493;
        uint64_t j = rnd % size;
        uint64_t tmp = vec[i]; vec[i] = vec[j]; vec[j] = tmp;
    }
    return std::move(vec);
}
```

Note that the solution is still incorrect since it doesn't provide uniform distributions for all ranges, as shown further below. It also does not utilize parallel computing, but it performs well: Computing 100 million indices took `3235.18 ms` on my i7-3610QM.

- front ; `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[0, ..., 1999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 front]
- middle ; `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[49999000, ..., 50000999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 middle]
- back ; `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[99998000, ..., 99999999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 back]
  The above distribution is looking random, even though the average seems to be a little low and bouncy in the beginning. Its global trend looks as follows.
- average course of `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 averages]
  The polynomial trendline deviates up to 5% from the global average, so the distribution is not uniform.
  And for some ranges, it gets worse:
- average course of `distributeIndices(0, 67108863)` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 another averages]
- front ; `distributeIndices(0, 67108863)[0, ..., 1999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 another front]
  This is clearly not an acceptable distribution.

An exemplary distribution with a flawless trendline can be obtained from [Severin Pappadeux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76082801), as of Apr 30, 2023. Following the suggestions, I added some parallelization.

```
uint64_t m = 0xd1342543de82ef95ULL; // taken from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf
uint64_t c = 0x1ULL;
inline auto lcg(uint64_t xi) -> uint64_t { // as LCG as it gets
    return m*xi + c;
}
inline auto cmp_lcg(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) -> bool {
    return lcg(a) < lcg(b);
}
auto distributeIndices(uint64_t from, uint64_t to) -> std::vector<uint64_t> {
    uint64_t size = to - from + 1;
    std::vector<uint64_t> z(size);
    tbb::parallel_for(uint64_t(0), size, [&](uint64_t i) {
        z[i] = from + i;
    }); // instead of std::iota(z.begin(), z.end(), from);
    tbb::parallel_sort(z.begin(), z.end(), cmp_lcg); // instead of std::sort(z.begin(), z.end(), cmp_lcg);
    return z;
}
```

To give an idea of performance boost via multithreading, computing 100 million indices on my i7-3610QM took `15925.91 ms` sequentially and `3666.21 ms` with parallelization (on 8 hardware threads).
On a computing cluster with Intel Xeon Platinum 8160 processors, I measured the `(#cpu,duration[ms])` results `(1,19174.65)`, `(2,9862.29)`, `(4,5580.47)`, `(8,3402.05)`, `(12,2119.28)`, `(24,1606.78)`, and `(48,1330.20)`.

It should also be noted, that the code is better optimized and runs much faster, when turning `cmp_lcg` into a lambda function, e.g. `auto cmp_lcg = [](uint64_t a, uint64_t b) -> bool { return lcg(a) < lcg(b); };`. This way, it performed best at `2608.15 ms` on my i7-3610QM. Slightly even better performance can be reached when declaring global variables `m` and `c` as `constexpr`, or making them local or literals, which led to a duration of `2542.14 ms`.

- average course of `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76082801 averages]
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76082801 averages zoomed]
  But when looking at the actual distribution, it becomes apparent that it is not random, but ordered:
- front ; `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[0, ..., 1999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76082801 front]
  The solution is incorrect regarding the task that distributions should appear to be random, but due to its mostly<sup>✻</sup> nice distributions, it is particularly useful for the previously mentioned MPI use case. So if there won't be any fully correct solutions, it will make an accepted answer as well — so long as there won't be given any plausible ranges where it has non-uniform distributions. *Plausible* here means, that values where the algorithm would run for at least several days, can be ignored.
  <sup>✻</sup><sub>The factor [0xd1342543de82ef95](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOehc.jpg) shows some weaknesses in the [spectral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_test), and I haven't yet found a reason not to use [0x9e3779b97f4a7c15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6LjT.jpg) instead.</sub>

After all this, it should be clear what it means that the task is to combine

1. perceived randomness of a
2. uniform bijective distribution of
3. plausible arbitrary intervals, with
4. high performance.

I am very curious if there even exist any correct and well-performing solutions to the problem!
A negative answer to this question, with a corresponding proof, would of course also be acceptable.

Even better than `distributeIndices(uint64_t, uint64_t) -> vector<uint64_t>` would be an approach to not have to create a vector, but merely iterating the indices in pseudo-random order, but that would require each pseudo-random index to be efficiently computable from its actual index (without iterating all the elements before it). I would be surprised it that is possible, but I'd gladly be surprised. Such approaches are always considered better than the vector-constructing ones, and are compared amongst each other by the duration of iterating 100 million indices.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253284/discussion-on-question-by-xamid-fastest-way-to-bring-a-range-from-to-of-64-bi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Related meta question (was automatically deleted (now only visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points and to the OP)): *[Will there be done something about questions being closed for false reasons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424345/will-there-be-done-something-about-questions-being-closed-for-false-reasons)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

The following solution constructs a bijective function F that maps a range of integers onto itself. This function can be used to compute a pseudo-random index directly from a source index such that the resulting pseudo-random indices are a permutation of the source indices.

There are three ideas (all borrowed from cryptography) that taken
together allow for the construction of such a function: 1) a
Pseudo-Random Function Family [(PRF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family), 2) a [Feistel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) network, and
3) a format-preserving-encryption [(FPE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).  While these ideas draw on
well-studied cryptography concepts, I believe the end product is
probably unqiue and should definitely be considered insecure.

The basic strategy is to encrypt the source index to produce the
target index. The secret sauce is to design the encryption to be
bijective and use a range of integers as the domain. I have dubbed
this method `feisty` for the use of a Feistel network.

## Pseudo Random Function Family

The first step in the construction is creating a PRF that returns a
pseudo-random value given a 64-bit input. We can create this family
using a single function that also takes a subkey parameter that is
used to select the particular function to use. The canonical PRF
example uses AES to produce a 128-bit pseudo-random value. We will
use the following function which is more efficient to evaluate
(although much less secure) and produces a 64-bit pseudo-random
value. The `s0` parameter is the source index and `s1` parameter is
the subkey.

```cpp
uint64_t pseudo_random_function(uint64_t s0, uint64_t s1) {
    auto a = s0 + s1;
    a ^= a >> 12;
    a ^= a << 25;
    a ^= a >> 27;
    return a * 0x2545f4914f6cdd1dull;
}
```

This function can be used directly to order the source indices
producing a pseudo-random permutation as in [Severin Pappadeux's
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76082801/1202808) which is
equivalent to constructing an FPE using a prefix cipher. The main
difference is that this PRF produces more "random" looking results
than using the linear congruent generator as shown in the following
plot.

[image: Iterated PRF]

## Feistel Network

Instead of using the PRF directly, we will apply a Feistel network
that leverages the PRF as its round function. The two key advantages
of the Feistel network is 1) the operation is guaranteed to be
invertible (i.e. bijective) even if the round function is not, and 2)
the number of output bits can be selected to be at most one or two
more than the number of input bits making the encoding range of the
network at most four times larger than the input domain. The minimum
number of rounds for security applications is suggested to be
three. The following class implements a balanced Feistel network.

```cpp
template<class PRF>
class FeistelNetwork {
public:
    FeistelNetwork(int number_of_bits, int number_rounds, PRF&& prf)
        : shift_((1 + number_of_bits) / 2)
        , mask_((uint64_t{1} << shift_) - 1)
        , nrounds_(number_rounds)
        , prf_(std::forward<PRF>(prf)) {
    }

    auto encode(uint64_t msg) const {
        auto [left, right] = split(msg);
        for (auto i = 0; i < nrounds_; ++i)
            round(left, right, Rounds[i]);
        return combine(left, right);
    }

    auto decode(uint64_t msg) const {
        auto [left, right] = split(msg);
        for (int i = nrounds_ - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            round(right, left, Rounds[i]);
        return combine(left, right);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> split(uint64_t msg) const {
        auto right = msg bitand mask_;
        auto left = (msg >> shift_) bitand mask_;
        return std::make_tuple(left, right);
    }

    uint64_t combine(uint64_t left, uint64_t right) const {
        return (left << shift_) bitor right;
    }

    void round(uint64_t& left, uint64_t& right, uint64_t constant) const {
        auto prf_value = prf_(right, constant) bitand mask_;
        auto r = left ^ prf_value;
        left = right;
        right = r;
    }

    static constexpr uint64_t Rounds[] = {
        0x88ef7267b3f978daull,
        0x5457c7476ab3e57full,
        0x89529ec3c1eec593ull,
        0x3fac1e6e30cad1b6ull,
        0x56c644080098fc55ull,
        0x70f2b329323dbf62ull,
        0x08ee98c0d05e3dadull,
        0x3eb3d6236f23e7b7ull,
        0x47d2e1bf72264fa0ull,
        0x1fb274465e56ba20ull,
        0x077de40941c93774ull,
        0x857961a8a772650dull
    };

    int shift_;
    uint64_t mask_;
    int nrounds_;
    PRF prf_;
};
```

## Cycle-walk and Feisty Permutation

If the source index range happens to be an even power of two, then we
can simply call `encode` on the Feistel network to map a source index
to a pseudo-random target index. In general, however, the Feistel
network may return an encoding that is outside the source index
domain. The solution is to simply call `encode` on the out-of-range
index until we get an index that is in the source index domain. This
recursion will terminate because the Feistel network encryption is
bijective and the domain is finite. For the worst case source index
range (i.e. one more than an even power of two), their will be an
average of almost four calls to `encode` for a balanced network or two
for an unbalanced network. The following class implements the basic
logic along with mapping the source index domain from `min,max` to
`0,max-min`.

## Results

All of the code and images can be found at
[GitHub](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git) in the `76076957`
directory. I used the following driver for testing and generating the
performance metrics all of which use three rounds in the Feistel
network. I wrote the code for clarity and I have not yet done any
performance work, although, I think the inner loops are already pretty
efficient.

```cpp
#include "core/util/tool.h"
#include "core/chrono/stopwatch.h"
#include "core/string/lexical_cast_stl.h"

template<class Work>
void measure(std::ostream& os, std::string_view desc, Work&& work) {
    chron::StopWatch timer;
    timer.mark();
    if (work())
        os << fmt::format("{:>12s}: work failed", desc) << endl;
    auto millis = timer.elapsed_duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>().count();
    os << fmt::format("{:>12s}: {:5d} ms", desc, millis) << endl;
}

int tool_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ArgParse opts
        (
         argValue<'m'>("range", std::make_pair(0, 16), "Permutation range min:max"),
         argValue<'r'>("rounds", 3, "Number of rounds"),
         argFlag<'p'>("performance", "Measure performance"),
         argFlag<'s'>("sort", "Sort index based on PRF")
         );
    opts.parse(argc, argv);
    auto [min, max] = opts.get<'m'>();
    auto rounds = opts.get<'r'>();
    auto measure_performance = opts.get<'p'>();
    auto sort_index = opts.get<'s'>();

    if (measure_performance) {
        PseudoRandomPermutation perm(min, max, rounds, &pseudo_random_function);
        measure(cout, "Permutation", [&]() {
            for (auto i = perm.min(); i < perm.max(); ++i) {
                auto code = perm.encode(i);
                if (code < perm.min() or code > perm.max())
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    } else if (sort_index) {
        std::vector<uint64_t> codes;
        for (auto i = min; i < max; ++i)
            codes.push_back(i);
        std::sort(codes.begin(), codes.end(), [](uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
            return iterate_prf(a, 3) < iterate_prf(b, 3);
        });
        for (auto elem : codes)
            cout << elem << endl;
    } else {
        std::set<uint64_t> codes;
        PseudoRandomPermutation perm(min, max, rounds, &pseudo_random_function);
        for (auto i = min; i < max; ++i) {
            auto code = perm.encode(i);
            assert(code >= min and code <= max);
            codes.insert(code);
            cout << i << " " << code << endl;
        }
        assert(codes.size() == max - min);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have not done any statistical tests, but have simply eyeballed the plots and based on the eyeball tests I believe this answer satisfies the criteria:

1. It looks random (cannot differentiate from std::shuffle).
2. It looks uniformly distributed (straight line cumulative sum).
3. It is efficient (tens of nanoseconds / index).
4. Computable directly from a single actual index.

### Basic Performance Measurements

```
39ns / index on Mac M1 Pro (arm64, MacOSX)
52ns / index on Intel Xeon ES-2698 @ 2.2Ghz (x86, Ubuntu 20.04)
```

### Randomness

The following two plots compare using `std::shuffle` versus `feisty`
for creating the pseudo-random permuation for 20k indices. The third plot shows the cumulative sum of the pseudo-random indices which should be a straight line for a uniform distribution.

[image: Shuffle, 20k]
[image: Feisty, 3-rounds, 20k]
[image: Feisty, cumulative sum]

### Round Behavior

Just for curiosity's sake, here are plots for using from 1 to 5 rounds
of the Feistel network. As suggested by theory, there needs to be a
least three rounds to achieve good results.

[image: Feisty, 1-round, 20k]
[image: Feisty, 2-rounds, 20k]
[image: Feisty, 3-rounds, 20k]
[image: Feisty, 4-rounds, 20k]
[image: Feisty, 5-rounds, 20k]

Comment: This is an impressive solution. You even solved the bonus task of immediate permutation of any element! I measured `4329.25 ms (4 s 329.25 ms)` for iterating 100 million indices. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xN4r1OgFVPm6aGku) is a compiling code snippet that clarifies in how I measured performance of this solution.

Comment: That is 43ns / element which is inline with my measurements of 39ns (M1 Max) and 52ns (Xeon). I just tried a tweak which unrolls the Feistel `encode` loop assuming three rounds and it dropped the times to 36ns and 46ns respectively. A meaningful improvement on the x86 hardware. If you need more performance, I can probably squeeze out a little more juice.

Comment: I hope my compiler unrolled that encode loop, given that I used a literal `3` as argument for `rounds`. I would be even more surprised if other people gave answers with immediate permutations that are faster than this one, especially seeing how poorly this question is received. I am already very glad I have some answer that deserves my bounty. But if you think your time could easily be beaten by a skilled cryptographer, you might want to consider squeezing. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea: to stuff an array with incremental indices, and thereafter - just shuffle it, using an own, system-independent rand-generator.

You did not request a cryptographically secured permutation, and here I used just a simple [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in this example. If you need to keep your shuffle cryptographically secured, I suggest you to use [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4). It has a good balance between security and performance.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// LCG params from: https://nuclear.llnl.gov/CNP/rng/rngman/node4.html
std::vector<uint64_t> distributeIndices(uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi) {
    uint64_t size = hi - lo + 1;
    uint64_t mask = 1;
    while(mask < size)
        mask <<= 1;
    mask--;
    std::vector<uint64_t> vec(size);
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        vec[i] = i + lo; 
    uint64_t rnd = (hi + size) ^ 0xBabeCafeFeedDad;
    for(uint64_t i = size - 1; i != 0; i--) {
        uint64_t j;
        do {
            rnd = rnd * 2862933555777941757ULL + 3037000493;
            j = rnd & mask;
        } while(j >= size);
        uint64_t tmp = vec[i]; vec[i] = vec[j]; vec[j] = tmp;
    }   
    return std::move(vec);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint64_t lo = atoll(argv[1]);
    uint64_t hi = atoll(argv[2]);
   std::vector<uint64_t> vec = distributeIndices(lo, hi);
   for (uint64_t x : vec)
        printf("%lu\n", x); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rnd % size` is far from uniform. Look at how `std::uniform_int_distribution` works.

Comment: `rnd % size is far from uniform`. This is true, but is not matter for this case. result of this - just some cells will be just swapped twice. But only one swap is enough for good randomization, so 2nd one is not matter.

Comment: Also, if you really worry about `rnd % size`, I can modify code, and generate unified rnd-output. But it will make code more slowly, maybe ~2x in worst case. I think, better to keep as is.

Comment: While for some bounds the results are really looking random and well-distributed, unfortunately your approach [is unreliable w.r.t. uniformity](https://imgur.com/a/McjlGai). I elaborated on this in my now updated question.

Comment: Of course, simple LCG is not good, for your deep tests. I stated about it in the original post. To make high quality uniform distribution, I already suggested you cryptographic RND generator, for example - RC4.

Comment: No, LCG (or, in correct terms, [affine_cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher)) can be used to generate uniform distributions, for which I mentioned the other answer as an example (with pictures) in the question. The non-uniformity stems from how you obtain your distribution from the ciphered values. Using a cryptographically secured permutation does not change anything about that.

Comment: Hm.. Maybe you right.. Can you test another approach with using `rnd % i` on your data suite? I updated code above.

Comment: @olegarch There is no logical reason why using `rnd % i` instead of `rnd % size` would fix anything. There is a [plotter](https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/scatter-plot.html) and [testing code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R8mI8DUDQbh08NU0) mentioned in my question if you'd like to experiment around, but to actually solve the problem, one probably has to think a little harder and use mathematics. The question is harder than what you'd typically find on Stack Overflow, which I suppose is also why many people downvoted in frustration.

Comment: OK, I removed `%`, used classic iterative probation. It decreases RND performance ~2x in worst case (avg 2 attempts per index), but distribution will be uniform. However, I still think, problem is not in `%`, but rather in LCG. Fro example, LCG always generates sequence odd-even-odd-even... What is not a random.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to just sort it using an [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with a whole [0...2<sup>64</sup>) unique mapping to itself, if LCG parameters are subject to [Hull–Dobell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#c_%E2%89%A0_0) conditions. Good spectral parameters are taken from *[Computationally easy, spectrally good multipliers for congruential pseudorandom number generators](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf)*.

You could easily adapt it to [TBB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks) vectors and parallel sorts.

Along the lines

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

#define func auto

uint64_t m = 0xd1342543de82ef95ULL; // taken from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf
uint64_t c = 0x1ULL;

inline func lcg(uint64_t xi) -> uint64_t { // as LCG as it gets
    return m*xi + c;
}

inline func cmp_lcg(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) -> bool {
    return lcg(a) < lcg(b);
}

func distributeIndices(uint64_t from, uint64_t to) -> std::vector<uint64_t> {
    std::vector<uint64_t> z(to - from + 1);

    std::iota(z.begin(), z.end(), from);

    std::sort(z.begin(), z.end(), cmp_lcg);

    return z;
}

static const char NL = '\n';

func main() -> int {

    auto q = distributeIndices(7, 23);

    for(auto v: q)
        std::cout << v << " " << lcg(v) << NL;
    std::cout << NL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice concept for parallelization. I used `tbb::parallel_sort` instead of `std::sort` for time measurement. Unfortunately, with `3666.21 ms (3 s 666.21 ms)`, it is still behind, but close. Sequentially, it took `15925.91 ms`. Results are also looking good.

Comment: @xamid Curious if [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html) will work better than TBB

Comment: The parallelization of std:: methods is done by adapting the parallelization schema in use (which usually is Intel's oneTBB). OpenMP tends to be a tiny bit faster than TBB, but as a non-standard preprocessor hack without shared memory data structures, it is much less flexible than TBB, a C++ standard compliant library compatible with `std::thread` (which OpenMP is not). So I don't use OpenMP and would recommend TBB to anyone who wants to implement some sophisticated parallel behavior. Incidentally, even the note behind your link recommends against using non-standard parallel mode extensions.

Comment: Well, parallel algorithms are now part of C++ standard, but quality of implementation still varies. https://www.cppstories.com/2018/11/parallel-alg-perf/

Comment: So if TBB is about the same speed wise, stay with TBB

Comment: The C++17 algorithms are exactly what I was talking about. The `std::execution::par` actually has no effect when not having a parallelization library around, which they can inject. So they are not faster than TBB when using TBB. But I wouldn't recommend using them, since they mess up exception handing in threads. Possibly that is a GCC and LLVM specific defect, I don't know what the standard says (e.g. an exception thrown in a `std::for_each(...)` running in parallel is not caught in the main thread). But Intel really did a much better job at implementing shared memory parallelization.

Comment: Also might be worthwhile to check how this approach and parallel sort will behave with growing number of CPUs/cores. Together with parallel std::iota

Comment: Your code performs much faster with `tbb::parallel_sort` when `cmp_lcg` is turned into a lambda. It should be noted, though, that upon visual inspection the results [look too ordered to suggest randomness](https://imgur.com/a/XqUtqiN).
I mentioned these points and also provided some measured durations based on different core amounts in my now updated question. Instead of `std::iota` I used `tbb::parallel_for`, but it did not give noticeably better timings on my laptop.
PS: Sorry for the late reply, I was suspended for a week for being impolite about close votes.

Comment: You could save some time constructing empty vector, then reserve(), then iota. Now in constructor there is a loop initializing with default value. You need just allocation, iota will do initialization anyway. Lambda being faster is probably a failure of the optimizer

Comment: Concerning your picture, you got LCG lattice structure, could check it in Wiki

Answer (score 0):

When something appears ordered, i.e. non-random, it means that it follows some recognizable patterns. Elements of a pattern repeat in a predictable manner. Therefore, by the nature of what a pattern is, it should be clear that the distributions of any [cryptographic hash function (CHF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) should not give away any patterns, because that would make it less secure.
For the same reason, such distributions must also be uniform, since otherwise there would be subsets of hashes that would be easier to attack.
Consequently, it seems like a safe bet to utilize some cryptographic hash function in order to meet the requirements of uniformity and random appearance. But cryptographic hash functions tend to be slow, and more work has to be done since their distributions are not bijective.

So while the following approach has not really great performance, it is meant to show that there are at least okay-ish solutions *that fulfill the specification*.

One of the fastest widespread CHFs is [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), which is used for the sake of this demonstration. It is well-defined, and therefore conforms with the "same results regardless of the used C++ implementation" requirement. It can be nicely adapted to the problem because it provides 128-bit hashes, which can be treated as single numbers in C++ (via GNU `__uint128_t`, or by using a library such as [@ckormanyos/wide-integer](https://github.com/ckormanyos/wide-integer)).

I tested with two implementations: [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) [[MinGW-w64 package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl)] and [@animetosho/md5-optimisation](https://github.com/animetosho/md5-optimisation).
OpenSSL turned out be be around **30% slower**. It probably was not designed to operate on such small inputs.

Newly created `md5.h`:

```
#ifndef _MD5_H
#define _MD5_H

#include <cstdint>
#include <ostream>

typedef __uint128_t uint128_t;
uint128_t md5(std::uint64_t num);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, uint128_t x); // in case you want to print uint128_t values

#endif // _MD5_H
```

Inserted into md5-optimisation's `md5.cpp`:

```
#include "md5.h"
uint128_t md5(std::uint64_t num) {
    MD5_STATE<std::uint32_t> hash;
    md5<std::uint32_t, md5_block_noleag>(&hash, &num, sizeof(std::uint64_t));
    return (uint128_t(hash.A) << 96) | (uint128_t(hash.B) << 64) | (uint128_t(hash.C) << 32) | hash.D;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, uint128_t x) {
    if (x >= 10)
        out << x / 10;
    return out << static_cast<unsigned>(x % 10);
}
// + main function removed
```

Note that the library contains numerous strategies. `md5_block_noleag` turned out fastest on my system for this use case.

Inserted into `main.cpp` (testing code from the question):

```
#include "md5.h"
#include <openssl/md5.h>
using namespace std;
#define S(X,n) (uint128_t(X) << 8 * n)
#define N(X) (S(X[ 3], 15) | S(X[ 2], 14) | S(X[ 1], 13) | S(X[ 0], 12) \
            | S(X[ 7], 11) | S(X[ 6], 10) | S(X[ 5],  9) | S(X[ 4],  8) \
            | S(X[11],  7) | S(X[10],  6) | S(X[ 9],  5) | S(X[ 8],  4) \
            | S(X[15],  3) | S(X[14],  2) | S(X[13],  1) | S(X[12],  0))
// e.g. MD5-hash(42) = "e8bdc34458096e6d18755f4c86df8b95" ; NOTE: MD5-hash(42) != MD5-hash("42")
// little-endian: e8bdc344 58096e6d 18755f4c 86df8b95 ; 309366199612997410650608664883390024597
// big-endian:    44c3bde8 6d6e0958 4c5f7518 958bdf86 ;  91403853391004256260858066647535837062 <- numeric value
uint128_t openssl_md5(uint64_t num) {
    unsigned char hash[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // length 16
    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init(&md5);
    MD5_Update(&md5, &num, sizeof(uint64_t));
    MD5_Final(hash, &md5);
    return N(hash);
}
```

Now, to convert a 64-bit integer into its MD5-hashed 128-bit integer, one could use `md5` or `openssl_md5`.

The idea follows the approach to concurrently sort integers w.r.t. their hashed values.

```
auto distributeIndices(uint64_t from, uint64_t to) -> vector<uint64_t> {
    auto cmp_md5 = [](uint64_t a, uint64_t b) { return md5(a) < md5(b); };
    uint64_t size = to - from + 1;
    vector<uint64_t> v(size);
    tbb::parallel_for(uint64_t(0), size, [&](uint64_t i) {
        v[i] = from + i;
    });
    tbb::parallel_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp_md5);
    return v;
}
```

Unless a faster way to utilize hash functions while keeping uniformity and establishing bijectivity is found, the task boils down to finding faster performing hash functions whose distributions do not look ordered (which **should** include **all** *cryptographic* hash functions).
So it seems that this question implicitly focuses on **cryptography** a lot more than I anticipated.

Computing 100 million indices took my i7-3610QM `153252.76 ms (2 min 33 s 252.76 ms)`.
For visual inspection, here is an exemplary distribution obtained this way, with plots:

- average course of `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 averages]
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 averages]
- front ; `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[0, ..., 1999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 front]
- middle ; `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[49999000, ..., 50000999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 middle]
- back ; `distributeIndices(42, 42+99999999)[99998000, ..., 99999999]` with polynomial trendline:
  [image: stackoverflow.com/a/76077930 back]